# Call CellContentClick method of a DataGridView from another Button

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, button, datagridview

I want to call the `dataGridView1_CellContentClick` method call inside that button. If I try to copy and paste the code from the cell content click method to button. the code doesn't work as it works inside the real method of data grid view call content click. Please tell me any code either any way from which this way I can use the code of cell content click of data grid view inside any button like I have shown in the picture. I want to run below code inside any button in a window from like I have shown inside picture. Thanks.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    for (int counter = 0; counter < (dataGridView1.Rows.Count);counter++)
    {
        ConnectDb.FileRow = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["FileRow"].Value;
        ConnectDb.FIRSTNAME1 = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["FIRSTNAME1"].Value;
        ConnectDb.LASTNAME1 = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["LASTNAME1"].Value;
        //...
        //Copy rest of cells to corresponding property
        //...
        ConnectDb.FIELD4 = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["FIELD4"].Value;
        ConnectDb.FIELD5 = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["FIELD5"].Value;
        ConnectDb.FIELD6 = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["FIELD6"].Value;
        MessageBox.Show("Your Data is selected");
    }          
}
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to learn more about databinding.

Comment: sir its Vb.net asnwer and i want c# answer . And my question is a bit tipical . i Really need answer exactly what i am asking in c# not in vb.net .Thanks

Comment: C# examples added. However, you can always convert C# to VB.NET and vise versa using online code converters like [this](http://converter.telerik.com/).

Comment: i get it sir . can you sir pls answer of this . i really need it urgently . private void buttonX5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // dataGridView1_CellContentClick();

        }

Comment: how can i code of that cell content event inside this button code whom i send in above comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189343/discussion-between-m-arslan-riaz-and-reza-aghaei).